# I want to render my input text value inside <p></p> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to render my input text value inside `<p></p>` tag. I'm able to render input text value to other input, but how can I render that inside `<p></p>` tag?

Work sample: https://jsfiddle.net/wpmnvbow/

HTML:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Type PCP Name" class="form-control" id="PCPName"  /><br /> <br />
Selected PCP:

<input id="selectedPCP" disabled="disabled" value="Not Selected" />
<!--<p id="selectedPCP"> hey <p>-->
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#PCPName').keyup(function(){
  var nameValue = $('#PCPName').val();
    if (nameValue == ""){
        $('#selectedPCP').val('Not Selected');
    }
    else{
    //alert(nameValue);
    $('#selectedPCP').val(nameValue);
    }

});
$('#PCPName').change(function(){
  var nameValue = $('#PCPName').val();
    if (nameValue == ""){
        $('#selectedPCP').val('Not Selected');
    }
    else{
    //alert(nameValue);
    $('#selectedPCP').val(nameValue);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `.text()`/`.html()` instead of `.val()` for setting the content of p element:

```
 $('#selectedPCP').text(nameValue);
```

You should trigger the keyup after attaching events to view the changes on load itself. also you can narrow down the code to:

```
$('#PCPName').keyup(function(){
    var nameValue = $('#PCPName').val();
    $('#selectedPCP').text(nameValue == "" ? 'Not Selected' : nameValue);
}).keyup();
```

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/g475kry5/)**

Answer (score 0):

`.val()` is for field element like `input` and `textarea`

```
$('#selectedPCP').text('Not Selected');
```

And into your condition:

```
if (nameValue == ""){
    $('#selectedPCP').text('Not Selected');
}
else{
    //alert(nameValue);
    $('#selectedPCP').text(nameValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [.text()](https://api.jquery.com/text/)

```js
$('#PCPName').on('keyup change', function () {
    $('#selectedPCP').text(this.value || 'Not Selected');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="Type PCP Name" class="form-control" id="PCPName" />
<br />
<br />Selected PCP: <p id="selectedPCP">hey<p>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use jquery' `append` on your p tag if you want to not overwrite your current text in the `p` tag. Also, change the ids into classes so it can work on both `input` and `p` elements.

https://jsfiddle.net/wpmnvbow/1/

Here's an updated fiddle that uses on `keyup` and a better approach: https://jsfiddle.net/wpmnvbow/2/